# onTouchEvent, status bar and canvas - differences in coordinate systems

Tags: java, android, touch, coordinates

I have created a custom `View`.
Just imagine a `Rect` drawn at its `Canvas`
at `x = 100`, `y = 100`, `width = 100`, `height = 100`
in bright blue (or any color you like)

Now I switch **off** the statusbar `->` the App is running in fullscreen.
Just imagine, I would touch **exactly** in the middle of the rectangle.
The coordiantes should be `150, 150` -- and as they are supposed to be, they are `150, 150`.

But now I **activate** the statusbar `->` the canvas shrinks a bit
`->` if you look at the screen, the rect is drawn `150px` below the statusbar -- this is what I wanted.
Now I touch again **exactly** in the middle of the rectangle.
The coordiantes should be `150, 150`,
but..  -- ***Jesus!*** --
The `onTouchEvent` coordinates **include** the statusbar height!
And the `Canvas` coordinates do **not**!

So what can I do to get the right `touch coordinates`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What methods do you used to get the x and y from MotionEvent? Have you tried getRawX() and getRawY()?

---update--

Sorry I think I've misunderstood something. What methods do you used? getY() or getRawY()?

---update again---

Are you handling onTouchEvent in Activity? Here I write some code for testing:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

private final Paint p = new Paint();
private final Paint p2 = new Paint();
private float lastRawX = 0, lastRawY = 0;
private float lastX = 0, lastY = 0;

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    p.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    p2.setColor(0xFF00FF00);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    lastX = event.getX();
    lastY = event.getY();
    lastRawX = event.getRawX();
    lastRawY = event.getRawY();
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // make the touch point big enough to be noticed.
    canvas.drawCircle(lastX, lastY, 3, p);
    canvas.drawCircle(lastRawX, lastRawY, 3, p2);
}
}
```

A red dot for getY() and a green dot for getRawY(). I've tested it in emulator(which I can use the mouse for simulating "accurate" finger touch) and in real device. In both I can see the red dot is drawn exactly at the place I touched and the green dot is drawn below the red one (exactly the height of the status bar).

But if handling onTouchEvent() in an activity, then getY() and getRawY() returns the same value.

Comment: I used getX() and getY() -- getRawX() would give me screen coordinates, and in this case, getX() does this also, thats the problem

Comment: --update-- I was handling onTouchEvent in my main Activity and _NOT_ in my custom view. That fixed it, BIIG thanks! :D -- +1 and accept

Comment: Anybody with this problem can fix it for all the touch events rather than just the first using getRawX() by translating the touches into Raw touch space: event.offsetLocation(event.getRawX()-event.getX(),event.getRawY()-event.getY());